# Need help understanding C++ libraries, compiling, linking, header files for specific project

Tags: c++, linux

This is my first stab at C++, also I know that the question is broad but I have a specific example that I'm working with so hopefully that will narrow everything down a bit.

I'm basically attempting to compile a C++ game manually in Linux (Ubuntu 14.04). The source code I am attempting to compile is located in this directory: https://github.com/akadmc/SmashBattle/tree/master/battle.

I'm CD'ing into the battle directory and, perhaps naively running

```
gcc *.cpp
```

I started seeing multiple issues as such:

```
compilation terminated.HealthPowerUp.cpp:1:21: 
fatal error: SDL/SDL.h: No such file or directory #include "SDL/SDL.h"
```

and

```
compilation terminated.LaserBeamPowerUp.cpp:1:21:
fatal error: SDL/SDL.h: No such file or directory #include <SDL/SDL.h>
```

After researching header file includes I concluded that includes without <>'s are basically just relative paths to include a header file, and that when they are wrapped in <>'s they can either lookup the file through a listing of directories specified in an enviornment variable, or a command line option.

So my first question is, is there any reason the developer used

```
#include "SDL/SDL.h
```

AND

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
```

in different files? There was no SDL directory in the source code...

After realizing that SDL was missing from the source code / environment in one way or another I did tinkering. I was pretty confused (and still am) because I downloaded the SDL source files, didn't see any header files, ended up building a version of SDL by using cmake, and then build. I realized afterwards that I just made a local executable and didn't yield any header files. Then I realized that I just needed the development library, downloaded that, and put higher in the directory tree and then included it at compile with

```
c++ *.cpp -I $HOME/Desktop/smashProject/source/
```

Afterwards, the previous header file errors went away - but I started getting errors like the following:

```
Text.cpp:(.text+0x17): undefined reference to `SDL_RWFromFile'
Text.cpp:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `SDL_LoadBMP_RW'
Text.cpp:(.text+0x34): undefined reference to `SDL_DisplayFormat'
```

And so on. Am I generally headed in the right path or do I have some misunderstanding about compiling, including development libraries, etc? Also I've read the the order of the compilation matters, and I'm not using any order + the developer didn't put a makefile in the source code or anything. I'm generally just confused as to how I should be doing this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds way to complex for your level. I'd be looking for a simple "hello world" type example. There is probably a makefile you were supposed to use. You need to specify library paths, libraries to link against, header paths and so on.

Comment: you might want to start by reading about `configure` script https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configure_script and then find a file in your copy of source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are on the right track.  However, now you need to have a linkage to the SDL libraries.  The -I just includes an extra library path but you have to actually link your assembly to the SDL files.

See this stack overflow question for more information.
[How to compile an example SDL program written in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19366064/how-to-compile-an-example-sdl-program-written-in-c)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you think of any reason why there would be  variation between #include <SDL/SDL.h> and #include "SDL/SDL.h" ?

Comment: The appropriate way to include SDL would probably be "SDL/SDL.h" and assumes you have a folder SDL with all of the headers within it in the same directory as your project.

Comment: the <> syntax is normally used for standard library includes.  See this for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename