# Compile an SDL project using gcc?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, sdl

How can I compile a sdl project using gcc in the linux command line without using Cmake?

EDIT;

```
gcc SDLGAME.c pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl2
```

but i get error.

```
gcc: error: Pkg-config: No such file or directory
gcc: error: sdl2: No such file or directory
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘--cflags’
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘--libs’; did you mean ‘--libs=’?
```

@HolyBlackCat

source code --->>

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) !=0)
    {
        printf("error SDL");
        return 0;
    }   
    SDL_Window* win=SDL_CreateWindow("Game",
                    SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                    SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                    500,500,0);
    return 0;
}
```

I get this error--->>

```
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
error SDL
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compile an example SDL program written in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19366064/how-to-compile-an-example-sdl-program-written-in-c)

Comment: Or: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64396979/

Comment: I couldn't do it

Comment: "couldn't do it" is not a problem description.

Comment: Try running `pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl2`, it will tell you the flags. Then add those flags at the end of your usual `gcc ...` command.

Comment: I tried but got an error  @HolyBlackCat

Comment: No, your version of ubuntu should be fine. Leave it as is. `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` is defined on _both_ my systems as `/run/user/1000` (1000 is my user id). I did: `export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/tmp/dir ; mkdir -p /tmp/dir` and it also ran okay. But, I did `unset XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` and it _still_ ran okay. I may have built and installed `SDL2` from _source_ on ubuntu because [IIRC] I had some issue about a year ago.

Comment: Try my first hack: `export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/tmp/dir ; mkdir -p /tmp/dir`. But, `SDL2` _should_ run without it. Okay, I just double checked. On my fedora system, SDL2 is installed from the binary package. But ... On my ubuntu system, I _did_ download the _source_ package and rebuild and install from that. (On ubuntu, it was reinstalled in `/usr/local`)

Comment: See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/28372/how-do-i-get-and-modify-the-source-code-of-packages-installed-through-apt-get for info on download/build of source packages

Comment: I did what it said, but this time I get the error "error SDL" in the if condition. @CraigEstey

Comment: On Linux with the  `pkg-config`  tool and package, compile your `SDLGAME.c` file with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g SDLGAME.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl2) -o sdlgame-binary` then use the GDB debugger

Answer (score 1):

*Caveat:* This isn't a total solution but some suggestions and is prefaced by top comment's and comments under OP's [now deleted] answer.

---

To review ...

After fixing the original issue by use of:

```
gcc -o SDLGAME SDLGAME.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl2`
```

OP running the program produces:

```
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
```

This may be a general issue about the ubuntu install itself. Some resources for that: https://askubuntu.com/questions/872792/what-is-xdg-runtime-dir and
https://askubuntu.com/questions/456689/error-xdg-runtime-dir-not-set-in-the-environment-when-attempting-to-run-naut

A workaround may be:

```
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/tmp/dir
mkdir -p /tmp/dir
```

But, I ran the program successfully on my home system, running fedora 29 and my ubuntu system running 18.04.5

On my systems, `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` was set to `/run/user/1000`. However, with/without the workaround and even doing `unset XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` worked on my systems.

*However:* On my ubuntu system, I had removed the standard `libsdl2` package and rebuilt and installed it from the *source* package a year ago due to some issues I had.

So, if the workaround doesn't work, I recommend `libsdl2` rebuild/reinstall from source.

Even if the standard package is working, when debugging your app, it can be helpful to be able to consult the `libsdl2` source.

Note that one change I made to your app was to add a `sleep(3)` at the bottom so you can *see* the window come up.

---

Here is the method I used to build/install from source:

It's probably necessary to uninstall/remove the *binary* `libsdl2` package. So, you'll have to do (e.g.)

```
sudo apt-get remove libsdl2 libsdl2-dev
```

Or, whatever the binary package is called [I forget]. But, those also came from: `apt-cache search libsdl2`

So, once that's cleaned out, what I did was:

1. Create a directory (e.g.): `$HOME/aptsrc`
2. `cd $HOME/aptsrc`
3. Download the source package [*without* `sudo`]: `apt-get source libsdl2`
4. This extracts several files (e.g. `*.tar.gz`, `*.tar.xz`, `*.dsc` and a directory. On my system, it was: `libsdl2-2.0.8+dfsg1`, but for you it may be different. Do (e.g.): `DIR=$HOME/aptsrc/libsdl2-2.0.8+dfsg1`
5. `cd $DIR`
6. Configure with: `$DIR/configure`
7. Run cmake: `cmake $DIR`
8. Run make with: `make`
9. Install with: `sudo make install`

Note that this comes from an internal script I created. Even after the `cd $DIR`, I *think* it's necessary to use full path on the commands [where indicated].

Now, the library *should* be installed under `/usr/local`. The output of `pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl2` should reflect this:

```
-D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include/SDL2 -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -lSDL2
```

The original output of this command would have looked like:

```
-I/usr/include/SDL2 -D_REENTRANT -lSDL2
```

This is for the *standard* install from the binary package, so if you *still* have that, the binary package may *still* be installed.

Otherwise, you should now be able to rebuild your app using the original `gcc` command. Now, it should be attached to the source built version of the library. You can confirm this with: `ldd ./SDLGAME` but just running it might be easier.